# Half data type in C++: What is the best way to convert float/double to half float/double consuming half the bytes.

Tags: c++, memory, cuda

I have a program which works with 10 million variables max because of memory limitations. I need to make it 20 million but with same memory.

So what is the best way to do that in C++?

are there any libraries for it?

and does the calculations with half data types consume less time?

also mention if Cuda Supports the half data types

Comment: If all your data was in `double`, then the answer would be to simply use `float` (with the caveat that you loose precision and range). However, there's really no "half-float". Also, the loss of precision and range would be considerable. Can you please edit your question to include the value ranges you need to support, as well as the minimum precision needed?

Comment: Oh, and since no modern CPU supports "half-floats" natively, it will *increase* the number of operations needed for calculations, as you need to implement all those operations (like addition, division, etc.) yourself in code. It's the usual trade-off between saving space or saving time.

Comment: yes I have used double and integer only. I need to increase the speed and the number of variables supported. I use Cuda for parallel programming. So virtual memory is not an option.

Comment: I guess you want to make the processing time per "variable" shorter? The problem is that even if you can halve the space used by those "variables" (for example by going from `double` to `float`) you probably won't be able to halve the processing time for each "variable", meaning if you double the number of "variables" you will increase the total processing time as well, you won't be able to keep it the same (or lower).

Comment: I want to increase ...  1. total number of supported variables. and 2. Speed while processing with same number of variables(say 10 mil vs 10 mil) :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Please note that is is a CUDA/GPU question, the IEEE 754 standard includes a BINARY16 floating point format, and a number of modern devices, including GPUs and ARM processors *do* support half precision floating point, be it fully IEEE 754 compliant or not

Comment: CUDA 7.5. supports [16-bit Floating Point (FP16) Data](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/new-features-cuda-7-5/)

Comment: @m.s I think that is the most sensible suggestion.  CUDA 7.5 has [defined storage and conversion mechanisms](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH____HALF__MISC.html#group__CUDA__MATH____HALF__MISC) for `float` <-> `half`  If you want to provide an answer I would upvote

Comment: @RobertCrovella in Cuda 7.5 half variables, it seems like we need to make use of functions for basic arithmetic, have they not use operator overloading for that purposes?

Comment: At the current time, for CUDA 7.5, a typical use case would be to use the intrinsics to covert the half data type to an ordinary `float` data type, then use ordinary `float` arithmetic.